# Drupal programmatically stop module hook

Tags: drupal-6, hook

I am using the autoassignrole module to assign ROLE#1 to anyone registering on my site.
Once signed in, users with ROLE#1 permissions can create users of their own for which I am using the uCreate module.

I have it setup so that when creating users via the uCreate module, the new user can be assigned ROLE#2 or ROLE#3 permissions.
The problem is at this point. The new user also inherits the ROLE#1 from the autoassignrole module.

**So, I put together a custom module and implemented hook_user and the plan is to detect when a user is being registered and programmatically stop the autoassignrole user_hook ... how do I do that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 potential solutions that I see at a high level:

1. If uCreate has a custom form to create users, you can alter that form to also include a on-submission database query that removes the role from the user being created
2. You can check if adding a condition to the autoassignrole module is possible-to attempt to disable autoassignment if the user's creation comes from an administration/uCreate add user URL